# Event (or IBAction) for when focus leaves textfield in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'd like to save the contents of a textfield to NSUserDefaults when the user's focus leaves the textfield. I can't figure out how to do that. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an NSControlTextEditingDelegate method that you are looking for:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
```

Basically you would save your information and then `return [super control:control textShouldEndEditing:fieldEditor];`

Comment: Ah okay - how do I set that up in Xcode? I'm very new to obj-c. All I know is the ctrl+drag trick to create outlets and actions.

Comment: No offense, but I really recommend going through some tutorials. This is a great site: http://cocoadevcentral.com/ Go through those tutorials and then you'll understand how to hook up delegates. IB is great, but at the end of the day you will have to write some code.

Comment: None taken ;-)  I dug around cocoadevcentral and several other sites and no one seems to explain exactly how you hook these up in Xcode. They only explain high-level theory which I now understand. Do you have specific tutorials that you recommend?

Comment: many cocoa objects have a property called delegate. Just do myTextField.delegate = anyObjectThatImplementsUITextFieldDelegateProtocol.

Comment: I found this to work for me! http://www.thepensiveprogrammer.com/2010/05/objective-c-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. When you have time go back to cocoadevcentral and work through the tutorials. It will take some time but it will save you a lot of frustration in the future.